# Selecting proper encoding format

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, format, ascii

I am in a situation where i am reading data from my arduino to my python program.
I am using:

```
ser_bytes = ser.readline()
ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

As you can see, i am using the `utf-8` format.

However, my program crashes from `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Let's see an error for example:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

`0xfe` is not the only character that i can't parse.
So far, i have received `0xfe, 0xff, 0xa9, 0xce`.

What are these characters, and what format should i use to receive them properly, since `utf-8` is not enough for this job?

Comment: they are accent characters, in arduino accent characters may be encoded using 2 characters instead of one https://forum.arduino.cc/t/string-to-int-extended-ascii-code-issue/654919

Comment: Please share `ser_bytes` _before_  decoding attempt. Moreover, elaborate your [mcve]. Byte sequence `0xfe, 0xff` _looks_ like utf-16 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: If the first bytes are FE FF then the encoding is `utf16` (big-endian is indicated by FE FF as well), not `utf8`.  but U+A9CE is an undefined code point.  Might be a problem with what the arduino is sending.